# Sending message from content script to a created window only sometimes works

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, react-hooks

I am using React together with Typescript to create a chrome extension.
I have a simple popup html in which i bootstrap my react component.

For now it's a simple button which has one method:

`popup.tsx`

```
const startWorkflow = async () => {
        await chrome.windows.update(window?.id!, {left: 400, top: 0, state: "normal", width: window?.width! - 400});

        chrome.windows.create({
                url: chrome.runtime.getURL("panel.html"),
                type: "panel",
                top: 0,
                left: 0,
                width: 400,
                height: window?.height,
                focused: false
            },
            async popupWindow => {
                setPopupWindow(popupWindow);
                const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({active: true, windowId: window?.id});
                if (tab.id != null) {
                    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {
                        action: "workflowCaptureStart"
                    });
                }
            });
    };
```

Here i create a new panel (which is also a react component). After creating it i send a message to my `content.ts` script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( (message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (message.action === "workflowCaptureStart") {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "lol"});
  }

  if (message.action === "workflowCaptureEnd") {
    console.log("Ending workflow capture.");
  }
})
```

Now i want to achieve to send a message from the content script to the (tab of the) window in which i created the `panel.html` and listen in this window (also a react component? for a message:

`panel.tsx`

```
const Panel = () => {

    const [status, setStatus] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        function lol(message: any) {
            if (message.action === "lol") {
                setStatus("Jihii");
            }
        }
        chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => lol(message));
        return () => {
            chrome.runtime.onMessage.removeListener(lol);
        }
    });

    const closeWorkflow = async () => {
        const window = await chrome.windows.getCurrent();

        // Trigger the saving of the workflow
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            action: "workflowWindowSave",
            content: {
                workflowWindowId: window.id,
            }
        })
    };

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={closeWorkflow}>Close Workflow</button>
            <div>{status}</div>
        </>
    );
};

// Render the popup
const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!);
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Panel/>
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

In which i have a simple useSate to keep track of the status which should come in through messages.
Now this only sometimes works. And i have no idea why.
Can anyone help here?